# Getting Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to sandbox.2checkout.com:443

Tags: php, ssl, curl, 2checkout

I am trying to implement `2checkout` payment gateway using `PHP` + `cURL` but while testing, I am getting CURL error which says:

> cURL call failed:-Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to sandbox.2checkout.com:443

What could be the possible cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2Checkout sandbox is currently utilizing the TLSv1.2 protocol, any prior versions of TLS will cause the same error to display that you have received. This protocol has not yet been implemented into production.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Your username and password are required to make any Admin API call.    
Twocheckout::username('testlibraryapi901248204');    
Twocheckout::password('testlibraryapi901248204PASS');    
Twocheckout::verifySSL(false);
```

Comment: verifySSL(false), really? That's dirty.